# i have problem with mysql in php causing crash

Tags: php

Know someone why its crashing site? Without it site is working but when im adding, site is crashing

```
$sqlcode2 = $polaczenie->query("UPDATE `uzytkownicy` SET `password` = '"$haslo"' WHERE `email` = '"$_SESSION["email"]"';");
```

Screenshot of code causing crash:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: string concatenation is done in PHP using a dot `.`. However, for SQL queries, you should use prepared statement to avoid SQL injections (among many other problems)

Comment: You should check your error logs or add the error to your question, it would help identify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your concatenation / joining of strings with variables.

When you link string with a variable, you should use a `.` (dot) between them, like this:

```
$something = "string here " . $some_var . "another string";
```

So, your code should be:

```
$sqlcode2 = $polaczenie->query("UPDATE `uzytkownicy` SET `password` = '" . $haslo . "' WHERE `email` = '" . $_SESSION["email"] . "';");
```

Note that sql statements should be prepared or sanitized to avoid unnecessary exploits.

Comment: @CoolestPoprostu please mark the answer as correct by clicking the tick if it is :)